# Cannot access session cookies in Electron app

Tags: session, cookies, electron

We are building an electron application using v.4.1.4. Trying to access the browser window's webContents session cookies, but I am getting an empty object or undefined. The browser window is loading our web app's url and in this use case the user has logged in which sets a cookie (to our url). I can inspect the browser window and can see the cookies that exist, so I'm trying to understand why the following code isn't working:

```
  let win = new BrowserWindow({ dimensions });
  win.loadURL(ourUrl);
  const ses = win.webContents.session;
  console.log(win.webContents.session.cookies); <--- empty
```

I thought I could get the webContents session cookies, but perhaps I have to set a cookie when the user logs in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`cookies.get` API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/cookies#cookiesgetfilter-callback) isn't very intuitive, try:

```
webContents.session.cookies.get({}, (err, cookies) => console.log(cookies))
```